# Soap call Method Parameter: return cannot be null. This is BP 1.1 R2211 violation

Tags: php, web-services, struct, wsdl, soap-client

I have been trying to call a bajaj webservice created in java **(which is not shared to me and cannot be changed from their side)** which should return response as byte array of PDF file and I want to call it through php code but it always gives me an error as follows:

Method Parameter: return cannot be null. This is BP 1.1 R2211 violation.

For calling web service I have used Soap Client and w.s.d.l link for same is as follows:

wsdl= http://webservicesdev.bajajallianz.com/docDownldWS/WebServiceImplService?wsdl

While trying to call soap->__getFunctions(), I am getting following in return:

```
Array
(
    [0] => anyType downloadFile(clientInfo $arg0)
    [1] => anyType getPolicyDoc(string $arg0, string $arg1)
    [2] => anyType getPolicyPdf(base64Binary $arg0, string $arg1)
 )
```

While trying to call `soap->__getTypes()` I am getting following in return:

```
  Array
  (
    [0] => struct clientInfo {
                           string errorCode;
                           string errorMsg;
                           string password;
                           string pdfMode;
                           string policyNum;
                           string str1;
                           string str10;
                           string str11;
                           string str12;
                           string str13;
                           string str14;
                           string str15;
                           string str2;
                           string str3;
                           string str4;
                           string str5;
                           string str6;
                           string str7;
                           string str8;
                           string str9;
                           string userId;
                       }
  )
```

Please help me in resolving the issue. I even have tried creating **struct object** but it resulted in same issue. 
I have done following experiment:

```
<?php
      class clientInfo {
        public $errorCode='';
        public $errorMsg='';
        public $password='somepass';
        public $pdfMode='WS_POLICY_PDF';
        public $policyNum='OG-18-9906-8430-00001806';
        public $str1='';
        public $str10='';
        public $str11='';
        public $str12='';
        public $str13='';
        public $str14='';
        public $str15='';
        public $str2='';
        public $str3='';
        public $str4='';
        public $str5='';
        public $str6='';
        public $str7='';
        public $str8='';
        public $str9='';
        public $userId='itsTheirUserName@s.in';
      }
      $clientInfo = new clientInfo();
      try {
         $soap = new SoapClient($wsdl, $options);
         $data = $soap->downloadFile(array(0=>$clientInfo));
         print_r($data);die;
      }
      catch(Exception $e) {
         die($e->getMessage());          }
?>
```